# Upper bound $I (t) := \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^d} \int_{\mathbb R^d} \frac{|x-y|^\alpha}{t^{d/2}} \exp ( - \frac{|\psi(x) - y|^2}{t} ) \, \mathrm d y$

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, gaussian

Let $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ and $\psi : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ be a $C^\infty$-diffeomorphism such that $\|\nabla \psi\|_\infty + \|\nabla \psi^{-1}\|_\infty < + \infty$. Let
$$
I (t) := \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^d} \int_{\mathbb R^d} \frac{|x-y|^\alpha}{t^{d/2}} \exp \left ( - \frac{|\psi(x) - y|^2}{t} \right) \, \mathrm d y.
$$

If $\psi$ is the identity map, then (by a change of variable) there is a constant $C>0$ such that
$$
I (t)  \le C t^{\frac{\alpha}{2}},
\quad \forall t >0.
$$

> Is there such an upper bound for general $\psi$ where $C$ possibly depends on $\psi$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration?

Comment: Why not consider the Taylor expansion of $\psi$ and then do some basic bounding? You can probably obtain something like $I_{\psi}(t) \leq C p(t^{\frac{1}{2}})$, where $p$ is the Taylor polynomial of $\psi$. Convolution with a kernel has linearity, and your quantity is positive, so the loss won't be significant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\al{\alpha}$No finite upper bound on $I(t)$ exists in such generality, even when $\psi(x)=2x$ for all $x$.

Indeed, using the substitution $y=\psi(x)-z\sqrt{t/2}$ and letting $Z$ denote the standard normal random vector in $\R^d$, we have
$$I(t)=\sup_{x\in\R^d}I_x(t),$$
where
$$I_x(t):=2^{-d/2}E\big|x-\psi(x)+Z\sqrt{t/2}\big|^\al \\ 
\ge2^{-d/2}(|x-\psi(x)|^\al-(t/2)^{\al/2} E|Z|^\al)
\to\infty$$
as $|x|\to\infty$ if e.g. $\psi(x)=2x$.

Comment: I guess you meant $E|x-\psi(x)+\sqrt tZ/\sqrt2|^\alpha$ rather than $E|x-\psi(x)+tZ/\sqrt2|^\alpha$.

Comment: @Akira : Thank you for your comment. This is now fixed.